# .Net - Cast or convert a boxed byte?, short? or int? to int?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, int, nullable

If I have an `object` reference that references a `byte?`, `short?` or `int?`, is there a way to unconditionally cast or convert that object reference to int? without writing separate code for each case?

For example:

```
byte? aByte = 42; // .. or aByte = null
object anObject = aByte;
//...
var anInt = (int?)anObject //As expected, doesn't work
```

Comment: Sorry but what you mean by "unconditionally cast"?

Comment: I meant "whatever it is - byte short or int, convert it to int"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use [`Convert.ToInt32(object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23511zys.aspx):

```
object o = ...; // Boxing...
int? x = o == null ? (int?) null : Convert.ToInt32(o);
```

Note that when you box an `int?`, `short?` or `byte?`, you always end up with a null reference or a boxed non-nullable value - there's no such thing as a "boxed nullable value" as such.

`Convert.ToInt32` will work for all the boxed types you've mentioned - although it would *also* work for things like a string "42" etc. Is that a problem?

Comment: So when boxing a `Nullable<T>` which contains a null value, then the resulting object == null?

Comment: @BorisB.: Yes. (The resulting reference - there's no *object* involved.)

Comment: @BorisB try it yourself, `ReferenceEquals((int?)null, null)` returns true.

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = (anObject as IConvertible).ToInt32(null);
```

Comment: Remember that he is dealing with nullables. If `anObject` is null, this will throw.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a reason why it's a nullable type and that that reason is it might be null, in which case our code would blow up

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, It doesn't apply to the question.

Comment: Why would you think that? It applies because he explicitly uses nullable types in his question and example. The fact that his particular code sample uses 42 doesn't negate that his code is dealing with boxed `byte?, short?, int?`, etc.

Comment: Right, I changed the example slightly

Comment: @AnthonyPegram, It depends on business rule. Maybe exception should be thrown? You know, don't you? The question isn't about that. Anyway, OP can easily add not null verification.

Comment: @Kirill, I disagree. Look at the semantics expressed via his question and code. He states he is dealing with nullable types. He wants to be able to unbox directly to another nullable type. All indications are that he should be able to successfully deal with nulls. Yes, he can do a null check. If you had shown it, there would have been 0 comments about your answer!