# Why are casting and conversion operations are syntactically indistinguishable?

Tags: c#, .net, casting, type-conversion, unboxing

Stack Overflow has several questions about casting boxed values: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7908101/net-cast-or-convert-a-boxed-byte-short-or-int-to-int), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970967/trying-to-cast-a-boxed-int-to-byte).

The solution requires first to `unbox` the value and only after that cast it to another type. Nevertheless, boxed value "knows" its own type, and I see no reason why conversion operator could not be called.

Moreover, the same issue is valid for reference types:

```
void Main()
{
    object obj = new A();
    B b = (B)obj;   
}


public class A 
{
}

public class B {}
```

This code throws `InvalidCastException`. So it's not the matter of *value vs reference type*; it's how compiler behaves.

For the upper code it emits `castclass B`, and for the code

```
void Main()
{
    A obj = new A();
    B b = (B)obj;   
}

public class A 
{
    public static explicit operator B(A obj)
    {
        return new B();
    }
}

public class B
{
}
```

it emits `call A.op_Explicit`.

Aha! Here compiler sees that `A` has an operator and calls it. But what then happens if `B` inherits from `A`? Not so fast, compiler is quite clever...it just says:

> A.explicit operator B(A)': user-defined conversions to or from a
>   derived class are not allowed

Ha! No ambiguity!

but why on Earth did they allow two rather different operations to look the same?! What was the reason?

Comment: You can also create [implicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2.aspx) conversions if you want.  Then it would be `B b = obj;`.

Comment: First off, this is a bad question for Stack Overflow because really it can only be *definitively* answered by someone on the C# 1.0 language design team. I don't believe any of those people are at present answering a lot of questions here. I would be happy to take a shot at it, but I cannot for the life of me figure out what question you are actually asking here.

Comment: @EricLippert Why do cast and convert operators look the same?

Comment: @voroninp That's exactly what Eric meant - it's a philosophical question that invites people to make a guess, but you won't get any definite answer unless the language designer(s) happen to be around.

Comment: @EricLippert. Btw, ECMA-335 does not prohibit the implementation of conversion to base class operators (i.e. special methods) in a derived class. And it looks like it was prohibited in C# only to avoid ambiguity between cast and convert operations.

Comment: @Wormbo When you say about guessing I only partially agree. As the shape of plane's fuselage is determined by design and  laws of nature, the same holds true (at least I believe it to be) for programming languages. We cannot tell for . Thus, besides hidden intentions must be some general rationality for such decision. And guess sometimes may be very insightful.

Comment: Well, if you put it that way, converting between e.g. int and float have always used the same syntax as casting between object references in the C-style languages. There is no reason to use a different syntax for explicit type conversions in C#, which are essentially the same as converting an int value to float.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your observation is, as far as I can tell, the observation that I made here:

http://ericlippert.com/2009/03/03/representation-and-identity/

> There are two basic usages of the cast operator in C#:
>
> (1) My code has an expression of type B, but I happen to have more information than the compiler does. I claim to know for certain that at runtime, this object of type B will actually always be of derived type D. I will inform the compiler of this claim by inserting a cast to D on the expression. Since the compiler probably cannot verify my claim, the compiler might ensure its veracity by inserting a run-time check at the point where I make the claim. If my claim turns out to be inaccurate, the CLR will throw an exception.
>
> (2) I have an expression of some type T which I know for certain is not of type U. However, I have a well-known way of associating some or all values of T with an “equivalent” value of U. I will instruct the compiler to generate code that implements this operation by inserting a cast to U. (And if at runtime there turns out to be no equivalent value of U for the particular T I’ve got, again we throw an exception.)
>
> The attentive reader will have noticed that these are opposites. A neat trick, to have an operator which means two contradictory things, don’t you think?

So apparently you are one of the "attentive readers" I called out who have noticed that we have one operation that logically means two rather different things. This is a good observation!

Your question is "why is that the case?"  This is not a good question! :-)

As I have noted *many* times on this site, I cannot answer "why" questions satisfactorily. "Because that's what the specification says" is a correct answer but unsatisfactory. Really what the questioner is usually looking for is a summary of the language design process.

When the C# language design team designs features the debates can go on for literally months, they can involve a dozen people discussing many different proposals each with their own pros and cons, that generate hundreds of pages of notes.  Even if I had the relevant information from the late 1990s meetings about cast operations, which I don't, it seems hard to summarize it concisely in a manner that would be satisfactory to the original questioner.

Moreover, in order to satisfactorily answer this question one would of course have to discuss the entire historical perspective. C# was designed to be immediately productive for existing C, C++ and Java programmers, and so it borrows many of the conventions of these languages, including its basic mechanisms for conversion operators. In order to properly answer the question we would have to discuss the history of the cast operator in C, C++ and Java as well. This seems like far too much information to expect in an answer on StackOverflow.

Frankly, the most likely explanation is that this decision was *not* the result of long debate between the merits of different positions. Rather, it's likely the language design team considered how it is done in C, C++ and Java, made a reasonable compromise position that didn't look too terrible, and moved on to other more interesting business. A proper answer would therefore be almost entirely historical; why did Ritchie design the cast operator like he did for C? I don't know, and we can't ask him.

My advice to you is that you stop asking "why?" questions about the history of programming language design and instead ask specific technical questions about specific code, questions that have a short answers.

Comment: An interesting note is that C++ has moved away from "C style casts" as the recommendation and added several conversion operators to be more explicit about what kind of cast is being done.

Comment: @Guvante: An excellent point. One could then ask the (bad for SO) follow-up question "If that's such a good idea then why has C# not followed C++'s lead here?" and now we have a "why not?" question about the reasons to *not* implement a complicated, confusing and expensive feature. This is why I push back on answering "why" and "why not" questions.

Comment: Well, original intention was to ask how to convert from a boxed value to specific type. When, for example, DataReader[0] contains a byte we can convert it to int only with (int)(byte)DataReader[0].  And then I've found out that requirement is universal for all types and looked at generated IL.  C#  designers allow unsafe casts but do not allow unsafe conversions. In my situation I have a third case for your former two from the article: "I have a value of some type and I expect it to have a conversion operator to the type I need. I do not care which type it really is.

Comment: @voroninp: Generating code for conversions from boxed values to other types requires essentially running the compiler's conversion rules at runtime; if that's what you want to do then use `dynamic`, or any of several helper methods that do just that, and take the performance hit.

Comment: @voroninp: I note in my original article that there are more than two possible meanings for a cast; those two were just the ones that concerned me for the purposes of that article.

Comment: And compiler reasonably shows an error when I try '(TGenericTypeParam)someVariable.' And if I only could ;-) Below in your article you write that it could be many ways of conversion, but here I speak only about standard operator.

Comment: @EricLippert Seems like I need to deepen my knowledge of CLR. I (don't even ask why) thought it was possible to tell it "just call static method of the type of this instance with the name op_Explicit returning particular type. As I see now, that was a wrong assumption. A kind of polymorphic behavior for static methods.

Comment: @voroninp:  Indeed, that's a fairly frequently requested feature.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion operators are essentially "glorified method calls", so the compiler (as opposed to the runtime) already needs to know that you want to use the conversion operator and not a typecast. Basically the compiler needs to check whether a conversion exists to be able to generate the appropriate bytecode for it.

Your first code sample essentially looks like "convert from object to B", as the compiler has no idea that variable can only contain an A. According to the rules that means the compiler must emit a typecast operation.

Your second code sample is obvious to the compiler, because "convert from A to B" can be done with the conversion operator.

Comment: This doesn't answer the quetion "Why are casting and conversion operations are syntactically indistinguishable?"

Comment: @juharr That's not a question well-suited to StackOverflow, however, as no one but that language's designers can offer other than conjecture.